# What are some major theories on picking the right number for the sample window size in time series analysis?

Tags: time-series, optimization, sample-size, online-algorithms, stochastic-approximation

for example the number of samples to run the moving average, or the number of samples for sequential hypothesis testing. Or if there is a control scheme going on what is the best time window for an affine controller. or when sampling from a distribution for approximation in stochastic control. This question is especially focused on real-time application and time series analysis where there is some computational cost associated with sampling as much as possible.

Comment: For computational cost (in terms of storage, for example) exponential smoothing models have big advantages.  For example, with simple exponential smoothing, you just need the previous forecast and the alpha parameter. Once alpha is determined by looking at a longer series (or borrowing the alpha from similar series, e.g. for a new product with little history) it's not re-estimated often (if ever).

Comment: Thanks, so in this model we pick only one observation back and derive alpha by minimization of the mean squared error is definitely one way. but how much more optimum this would be comparing to doing the same method with more observations? or what if we were going to predict next 10 observations?

Comment: As with most things in statistics, more data is more helpful and will help better estimate alpha (and determine if simple exponential smoothing gives good results).  Simple exponential smoothing models are usually used for short term forecasts -- the forecasts are flat, so you will basically be predicting the next 10 observations will be stable.